# How can I get values in client from server in python opcua

Tags: python

I tried:

```
client = Client("opc.tcp://192.168.0.104:16664")
try:
    client.connect()
    root = client.get_root_node()
    value = ua.Variant
    clt_1 = client.get_server_node().get_children()
    var = ua.VariantType
 finally:
    client.disconnect()
```

Using ua_variant or ua.Variant

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: clt_1 and var get wrong values than I need(on server). Here program on C++ from I must to rewrite code on python.

Comment: UA_Variant value; /* Variants can hold scalar values and arrays of any type */
  UA_Variant_init(&value); 
  if(UA_Variant_isScalar(&value))
  {
   printf("var id=%-24s val=%14s\n", vid->id, data_to_str(value.data, 0, value.type)); 
  }
  else
  {
   printf("var id=%-24s val array:\n", vid->id);
   for(uint32_t i=0; i < value.arrayLength; i++)
   {
    printf("%14s", data_to_str(value.data, i, value.type));
    if(i > 0 && i % 7 == 0)
     printf("\n");
   }
   printf("\n");
 }

}